# How do I find how many times an integer occurs and the longest sequence by reading it from a file?

Tags: java

I have to have the user input an integer, then by reading a file I have to find how many times that integer occurs and then the longest sequence of numbers. I think I generally have the method to find these two things but I don't think that I'm reading from the file quite right. I'm using eclipse so does my file have to be in a certain place for it to be read or is my code just completely wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;


    int[]data;
    int []counter;
    int temp;



        random.data = new int[5000];
        try{
            random.readDataFromFile();
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
        random.findInteger();

        random.longSequence();
    }
    //method to receive the input from the user and prints the number of times that the value occurs 

    public void readDataFromFile() throws Exception {
        java.io.File infile = new java.io.File("5000RandomNumbers.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(infile);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            data[i] = input.nextInt();
            }
        input.close();
    }


    public void findInteger(){

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);



        //ask user for an integer
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer value");

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            data[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        input.close();

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            temp = data[i];
            counter[temp]++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <counter.length; i++){
            if (counter[i] > 0 && counter[i]==1){
                System.out.println(i + "occurs" + counter[i] + "times");
            }

            else if (counter[i]>= 2){
                System.out.println(i + "occurs" + counter[i] + "times");
            }
        }
    }

    //method that prints out the longest increasing sequence in the data
    public void longSequence(){
        int count = 1;
        int max = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
            if (data[i] >= data[i-1]){
                count ++;
            }

            else{
                count = 1;

            }

            if (count > max){
                max = count;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(max);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a HashMap

```
HashMap hmap = new HashMap();

hmap.put(key, value);
```

You would have your key as the int that you are checking for and the value as the counter.